# how to check for certain file extension in a folder with php

Tags: php, file-extension

I have a folder named `uploads` with a lot of files in it. I want to find out if there is a `.zip` file inside it. How can i check if there is a `.zip` file inside it with php?

Comment: [glob](http://php.net/glob) should do the trick, no?

Comment: by using `glob($value.'/*.zip')`

Comment: This question has like a dozen answers already on SO. Do the minimum amount of research before asking.

Comment: Expanding the answer from Bernhard (credits to him) you can do regular checks like if (count ($result) > 0){ //your code }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

```
$result = glob("my/folder/uploads/*.zip");
```

It will return an array with the *.zip-files.

Answer (score 3):

This also could help, using [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param string $directoryPath the directory to scan
 * @param string $extension the extintion e.g zip
 * @return []
 */
function getFilesByExtension($directoryPath, $extension)
{

    $filesRet = [];
    $files = scandir($directoryPath);
    if(!$files) return $filesRet;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if(pathinfo($file)['extension'] === $extension) 
            $filesRet[]= $file; 
    }

    return $filesRet;
}
```

it can be used like

```
 var_dump(getFilesByExtension("uploads/","zip"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer is already given by @Bemhard, i am adding more information for future use:

If you want to run script inside your `uploads` folder than you just need to call `glob('*.zip')`.

```
<?php
foreach(glob('*.zip') as $file){
    echo $file."<br/>";
}
?>
```

If you have multiple folders and containing multiple zip files inside the folders, than you just need to run script from root.

```
<?php
$dir = __DIR__; // will get the exact path
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir'); // filter is directory or not.

$i = 1;
foreach ($dirs as $key => $value) {
    foreach(glob($value.'/*.zip') as $file){
        echo $file."<br/>"; // this will print all files inside the folders.
    }   
    $i++;
}
?>
```

One Extra point, if you want to remove all zip files with this activity, than you just need to [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) file by:

```
<?php
$dir = __DIR__; // will get the exact path
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir'); // filter is directory or not.

$i = 1;
foreach ($dirs as $key => $value) {
    foreach(glob($value.'/*.zip') as $file){
        echo $file."<br/>"; // this will print all files inside the folders.
        unlink($file); // this will remove all files.
    }   
    $i++;
}
?>
```

References:
[Unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)
[Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)